# Move li elements with certain class into and div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the .append function in jquery. 
I have a div with li elements in it. They have different classes, lets say odds and evens. 
I would like the li's with the class "odd" moved into another div with li's in it. 
How can I do this? 
Here is my setup: 
**Edit**. This was in valid markup, I just didn't put all in. Fixed now for others.

```
<div id="col1">
    <ul>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="even"></li></ul>
</div>
<div id="col2">
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**So then the output is:**

```
<div id="col1">
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
</div>
<div id="col2">
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not valid html. `<li>`elements must be under `<ul>` or `<ol>`elements

Comment: Chrome renders the `<li>` elements just fine without `<ul>` or `<li>`. They're just not indented, or numbered, or very useful.

Comment: @mblase75: it's just not valid html and can produce unexpected result.

Comment: @mblase75: Doesn't matter what Chrome (or any other browser) does, invalid HTML is still invalid HTML and relying on a browser doing anything special with invalid HTML is just asking for pain and suffering.

Comment: @muistooshort My point was that Chrome's DOM renderer leaves them as-is, without trying to wrap a `<ul>` around them. So they *should* be nested that way, but saying they *must* be nested that way is incorrect.

Comment: @mblase75: No, they **must** be properly nested to future proof the HTML. If Chrome's rendering of invalid HTML changes next week then kidA could have a pile of garbage on their hands. Go talk to someone that is (still) stuck using IE6 because they have thousands of pages and apps built with non-standard HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have `<div>` elements which you are moving elements into you can try this:

```
$("#col1 li").each(function(){
    var $li = $(this);
    if ($li.hasClass("odd")) $("#odd").append($li);
    if ($li.hasClass("even")) $("#even").append($li);
});
```

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/jq8bW/

Comment: This works, but only gets the first li with odd then stops. Is there a way to get all the elements?

Comment: should work fine. Double check your html is valid with opened and closed elements.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<li>` must be contained inside a  list `<ol>` or `<ul>`.

First, append `<div id="col2">`, but that div must also contain a `<ul>` or `<ol>` to be valid. Then append the odd `<li>` to the new list.

```
// Create <div id='col2'><ul id='col2-list'></ul></div>
$("#col1").after("<div id='col2'><ul id='col2-list'></ul></div>");

// Place the list elements inside it.
$("li.odd").appendTo($("#col2-list"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have valid html structure like this one:

```
<ul id="col1">
    <li class="even"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="odd"></li>
    <li class="even"></li>
</ul>
<ul id="col2">
</ul>
```

Here the jQuery code:

```
$('#col1 > .odd').each(function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo('#col2');
});
```

**Edit:** the use of `.detach()` is not mandatory.

Comment: I don't think you need to detach the DOM element before appending it to a new location.

Comment: I guess you're right. Makes more sense in my mind to detach it prior to appending it :-)